# Send MIDI note to virtual port with Java

Tags: java, midi, javasound

I want to send a MIDI note to a virtual port using Java. To send a MIDI note middle C (60), I do this:

```
public static void main(String[] main) throws MidiUnavailableException, InvalidMidiDataException, InterruptedException {
    final MidiDevice.Info[] midiDeviceInfo = MidiSystem.getMidiDeviceInfo();
    for (MidiDevice.Info info : midiDeviceInfo) {
        System.out.println(info.getName());
    }

    MidiDevice.Info midiInfo = Arrays.stream(midiDeviceInfo)
            .filter(midiDefInfo -> main[0].equalsIgnoreCase(midiDefInfo.getName()))
            .findFirst().orElseThrow();

    final MidiDevice midiDevice = MidiSystem.getMidiDevice(midiInfo);
    midiDevice.open();
    Receiver receiver = midiDevice.getReceiver();
    final ShortMessage messageOn = new ShortMessage();
    final ShortMessage messageOff = new ShortMessage();
    messageOn.setMessage(ShortMessage.NOTE_ON, 1, 60, 112);
    messageOff.setMessage(ShortMessage.NOTE_OFF, 1, 60, 0);

    receiver.send(messageOn, -1);
    Thread.sleep(1000L);
    receiver.send(messageOff, -1);
}
```

Using MIDI-studio from MacOS, I created 'MyVirtualPort':

[image]

When running the program, it prints the available devices:

```
Gervill
Real Time Sequencer
MyVirtualPort
MyVirtualPort
```

When I pass "Gervill" as param, I hear the middle C for 1 second from my speakers. When picking the second "MyVirtualPort", an Exception is thrown for MIDI IN not available. When picking the first "MyVirtualPort", the program runs fine and it seems to send the messages. However, I see no activity on the virtual port.

I tried to run the program on Windows using loopMidi (https://www.tobias-erichsen.de/software/loopmidi.html), but the same thing happens: program runs fine and seems to send messages correctly, but nothing happens on the virtual device. Setting it to the default plays the middle C successfully on Windows as well.

What am I missing here? I am a newby to MIDI, so it is perfectly possible this is something trivial.

Comment: The Gervill test proves that your program works correctly. This appears to be a problem with the MyVirtualPort.

Comment: Thanks @CL . The loopMidi receives a midi note when send from a stream deck, so that one is functioning fine. It does not receive the midi not from my program, so there must be something different here.

Comment: Have you connected a software synth to the other side of the virtual port ? If not it's possible that the virtual port simply discards your message. Your code looks OK. I use a similar approach in Java with loopMidi on Windows (or virmidi on linux), it works. Also in the first print loop, use MidiDevice.getMaxReceivers() to detect the output MidiDevices.

Comment: Thanks @jjazzboss. On windows I tried to connect to ableton live using the same loopMidi channel. Maybe I did that wrong, but stream deck is able to send midi notes to to ableton live using that loopMidi channel. On my mac, when adding MidiSystem.getMidiDevice(info).getMaxReceivers() to the printing loop, it prints -1 for the first 3 and 0 for the last one.